# JPA Relationships: What could "BE" stand for?

Tags: java, jpa

I've found a blog post about [14 High-Performance Java Persistence Tips](https://vladmihalcea.com/14-high-performance-java-persistence-tips/) and stumbled upon an abbrevation used in an image in Chapter 7 *Relationships*: "BE".

BE is only used for one-to-one mappings in this case.

What does it stand for?
Could he mean "bidirectional entity" that has the `mappedBy` attribute?

[image: Hibernate Relationship Performance Comparison]

Comment: Educated guess: [Bytecode Enhancement](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/pc/BytecodeEnhancement.html)

Comment: I think that's it. Makes total sense.